# Why does make tell me "Command not found"?

Tags: windows, makefile, mingw

I have the following simple makefile:

```
all:
    fat_imgen.exe
```

Where `fat_imgen.exe` is an executable in the same directory as the makefile.  When I try and run this however this happens:

```
>make
fat_imgen.exe
make: fat_imgen.exe: Command not found
make: *** [all] Error 127
```

If I run `fat_imgen` from that same command prompt then it starts as expected - why can't make find `fat_imgen.exe`?

This is all running under Mingw / Windows.

Comment: ./fat_imgen.exe ? (just guess)

Comment: @Alex Yeah, that did the trick

Comment: Wow, that could use some 'splaining.

Comment: @Hans Well `./` is the GNU shell syntax for "execute something in the current directory" and would be needed under a GNU shell.  My guess is that make is somehow emulating this behaviour, although everything I've read indicates that make should be simply passing commands to the shell, and the shell should be cmd.exe so it still doesn't really make sense!

Comment: @Kragen: The shell that make uses is /bin/sh, not cmd.exe

Comment: @camh According to [the documentation](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/make/Choosing-the-Shell.html) make uses the value of `%SHELL%` or `%COMSPEC%` - `%SHELL%` wasn't set and `%COMSPEC%` is cmd.exe.  Besides, I don't have a unix like shell installed on my system as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a simple commend like the name of an executable, GNU make will start the executable directly. If the directory where the executable is found is not in the PATH/path, make will fail.

If you put the directory in the path, your makefile should work normally.

Also, as suggested in a comment by @AlexFarber, by adding '`./`' GNU make will assume a more complex command (since not all shells are created equal), and hand the command over to the configured shell. That will work, since the shell is created in the directory where the command is then found.